# text box input in for loop and print text in scrollbox

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, input, textbox

Sorry if this is already asked. I have been searched for 2 days now, and I can't find the answer.
I am pretty new to coding so probably that's why I can't find the mistake I am making.

I want the user to be able to input 2 names in the textbox like this:

```
John
Peter
```

And if the user will press the <kbd>Vul script</kbd> button I want the output in the scrollbox to look like this:

```
create user "JOHN" identified by "JOHN";
Grant CONNECT to "JOHN ";
Grant RLOCUSR to "JOHN ";
create user "PETER" identified by "PETER";
Grant CONNECT to "PETER";
Grant RLOCUSR to "PETER";
```

The code above should be outputted as text in the scrollbox.
But that doesn't happen.

Here the full code:

```
# Tkinter import ( The graphic user interface )
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import scrolledtext


# scripttext ( creat user ect ) script plus name copy into scrollbox
def vulscript():
    vultext = textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    for names in [vultext]:
        scripttext = "create user \"" + names.upper() + "\" identified by \"" + names.upper() + "\";" \
             "\n""Grant CONNECT to \"" + names.upper() + "\";" \
             "\n" "Grant RLOCUSR to \"" + names.upper() + "\";" "\n"
        scr.insert(0.0, scripttext)


# Clearbutton function
def clear():
    textbox.delete(1.0, END)
    scr.delete(1.0, END)


# Making the screen
root = Tk()
root.title("Webnaam toevoegen script")
root.geometry("710x500")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
root.configure(bg='#f0f5f5')

# Script vul button
vulbutton = Button(root, text="Vul script", bg='#d1e0e0', command=vulscript, width=7)
vulbutton.grid(row=0, column=0)
# Clear button
clearbutton = Button(root, text="Clear all", bg='#d1e0e0', width=7, command=clear)
clearbutton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)

# Name label and text box next to it
namelabel = Label(root, text="Name", bg='#f0f5f5')
namelabel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
textbox = Text(root, width=18, height=29)
textbox.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N)

# script label
scriptlabel = Label(root, text="Script", bg='#f0f5f5')
scriptlabel.grid(row=0, column=2)

# Scroll tekst window
scrolW = 30
scrolH = 3
scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=60, height=29, wrap=WORD)
scr.grid(row=1, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

I added a picture with some explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have to do is to split your vultext where there is a linebreak:

```
def vulscript():
    vultext = textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    vultext=vultext.split('\n')
    print(vultext)
    for names in vultext:
        scripttext = "create user \"" + names.upper() + "\" identified by \"" + names.upper() + "\";" \
             "\n""Grant CONNECT to \"" + names.upper() + "\";" \
             "\n" "Grant RLOCUSR to \"" + names.upper() + "\";" "\n"
        scr.insert(0.0, scripttext)
```

Comment: create user "JOHN" identified by "JOHN"; Grant CONNECT to "JOHN "; Grant RLOCUSR to "JOHN "; create user "PETER" identified by "PETER"; Grant CONNECT to "PETER"; Grant RLOCUSR to "PETER";

-------This is text is not the problem. This is the text which should show up in the scrollbox. This text is an example how i wanna have it outputted into the scrollbox. The problem is in the for in loop i think. Some how when you type 2 names it shows up as this:---->

create user "JOHN PETER" identified by "JOHN PETER"; Grant CONNECT to "JOHN PETER"; Grant RLOCUSR to "JOHN PETER"

Comment: did you tried my solution? Replace your vulscript method to the one I proposed

Comment: yes i tryed. somehow i messed it up. got out of bed and tryed again. it works. this is amazing thank you so much.

Comment: What i do not understand is why it works though. would you mind explaining me what the split('\n') does ?
if i am not mistaking the splits makes it read tru every single line. but why the ('\n')?
Again thanks for the help. Realy i realy appreciate it.

Comment: what `split('\n')` does is to split a string every time it finds a `'\n'` in the string, and give the output in a list. So if you have `"John\nPeter"` after splitting it will be `["John","Peter"]`. Here `\n` is the command to break line. Before splittinf your vultext is one string like `"John\nPeter"`. If it worked please remember to accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: Use `splitlines()` instead of `split('\n')` is more descriptive.